# How to use Finger Swipe in Horizontal List View

Tags: android, image, listview, swipe

Hi Friends.

I have one horizontal `ListView` containing images.

Now I want to move next Image when User Swipe on the Screen.

My problem is normally when user swipe on screen lots of item of `ListView` is moved on Screen. I want to bind that Item. If user Swipe on screen only next Item should be displayed.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use `ViewPager` which is exclusively made for this purpose ?

Comment: But I had already used Horizontal List view and I cant change it now because if I will change it now I would have change alot. And I passed Data through JSON.

Comment: Isnt this possible in ListView?

Comment: @PoojaRoy:can u try view flipper

Comment: I cant because the Item in the list are not fixed.

Comment: @Pooja:I can't say it is impossible but you have to customize it, rather i recommend using `ViewPager` which is damn easy to implement and I guess it wouldn't need much effort to change your code.

Comment: ok do you have simple code for that

Comment: @PoojaRoy:Try with these.. http://sampleprogramz.com/android/viewflipper.php

Comment: @PoojaRoy: btw what you are showing in list item ?

Comment: @PoojaRoy You have to check it with some condition. You can't do directly if you want this.

Comment: Ok @PiYusHGuPtA Which condition

Comment: @PoojaRoy Do you need some reference for this. I have similar to this but static images..and you have to change according to you

Comment: Ok Then Give me those Reference

Comment: See this http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/11/horizontal-listview-in-android-example.html

Comment: I already used this for Horizental listview. But I got problem in swiping. When user swipe on screen only next item should be focused

Comment: So in this all images swiped??

Comment: yes In that example if user swipe on screen all images swiped.

Comment: @PoojaRoy There is thumbnails images like gallery so that images swipes?

Comment: yes I hav Thumbnails images as a list items and It showd move to next position on Item when user swipe on screen